# iphone social networking sharing functionality sdks

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sdk, social-networking, sharing

I'm looking for an sdk that can be integrated into native iphone apps to add social networking sharing functionality.

I'm familiar with AddThis, but it doesn't look like they have anything specifically built for the iphone.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
ward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this : http://www.addthis.com/help/ios-overview

AddThis has released an iOS Sdk

Answer (score 0):

There's [OpenFeint](http://www.openfeint.com/) and the forthcoming GameCenter in iPhone OS 4.

Comment: yeah I saw that.  I think I'm looking for something closer to addthis where I can present a user with the ability to share a url with a variety of services.